# How to pass message and data from method

Tags: oop, error-handling

I'm a mostly self taught programmer and one aspect I've never really understood is how to return data (term used loosely) and a status message from a method.

For example, say I have a method that takes a search term and returns the result of a query.  If the caller gets an empty dataset back, how would it know if it's empty because there are no matches or empty because there was an error in the connection to the database.

I've used APIs where an out or ref parameter was used, but it seems less than ideal.  Perhaps this is the whole point of exceptions.  The method would throw an exception if it can't connect to the db, so the caller would know if it received no results and no exceptions then there were simply no results.  Would I create my own object that contained both the data an a status message?

Maybe I'm overthinking this or am missing some fundamental point of OOP.

I'm looking to understand what the best way of returning status or error messages AND data from a method.

I wasn't sure if this belonged on Programmers or StackOverflow since it could be considered subjective, sorry if Stack is the wrong place for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is part of the point of exceptions.

In his book [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) the author talks about how it can cause confusion to start having out parms, or return values on what would otherwise be void methods.

It makes it harder to understand code just by reading it.

For example people.Find("John") should return a list of Johns, or a single John or throw an exception.

The caveat here is that exceptions can be expensive and so you don't want to use them for control flow.

So for searching, if it doesn't matter WHY there are no results, then just return null (or an empty list.)

Answer (score 1):

I personally  prefer using `out` for returning a status and a value in a method.
The method should return a status `enum`, and the result as an out parameter.

```
ResultTypeEnum MyMethod(in param1, blah param2, out MyType returnValue);
```

If you need more than one parameter returned, I would suggest creating a struct or class that contains all the results:

```
struct MyType {
   int blah;
   Myblah hello;
}
```

This way you don't have multiple `out` parameters and don't overload your method with confusing parameters.

Throwing an exception should be left as a last resort. Only if there's a critical error in the method that should require immediate attention you should throw an exception. If you just want to return a method's state you should use enums.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use exceptions for "normal program flow." Now when it comes to user input, I generally consider mistakes to be pretty normal, but the question here is whether being unable to connect to a database is "normal." -- I also find myself wondering if a "find" function should be doing things like connecting to a database.

I suggest that you make connecting to the database a separate call. Maybe a `DatabaseConnection` object that you pass to the find method, or maybe the class that has the find method also has an isConnected method so the caller can check that way.